# Has anyone setup tomcat to run virtual hosts using mod_jk

Tags: macos, tomcat, virtual, mamp, host

I work in OSX primarily with mostly PHP.  Normally I work locally using MAMP and virtual hosts setup in my httpd.conf so that I can point a browser to http://some-project and have as many projects as I need setup.

We have a project coming up where we need to serve JSP pages and I would like to set up my local apache server to serve only JSP files to Tomcat and everything else to MAMP using the same virtual hosts setup in:

~/applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf

So far I have:

1. Successfully installed Tomcat
2. Placed mod_jd.so in

   ~/applications/MAMP/Library/modules/mod_jk.so
3. Added the module by placing:

   LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

in

```
~/applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf
```

4. Created /Library/Tomcat/Home/conf/jk/workers.properties
   and added the following lines:

   workers.tomcat_home=/Library/Tomcat
   workers.java_home=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home

   ps=/ 
   worker.list=ajp12, ajp13

   worker.ajp13.port=8009
   worker.ajp13.host=localhost
   worker.ajp12.type=ajp13 
   worker.ajp13.mount=/*.jsp
5. added the following lines:

   JkWorkersFile /Library/Tomcat/Home/conf/workers.properties 
   JkLogFile /Library/Tomcat/Home/logs/mod_jk.log JkLogLevel debug

to 
     ~/applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf

I cannot start my MAMP however when these last two lines are present in my httpd.conf.

Does anyone work like this?

Any tips?

Any clear ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use mod_proxy. It's much easier to setup. It's less performant, but it shouldn't be a concern in a development environment. For performance, I think mod_proxy + ajp is the Apache-recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

I've found with MAMP that it won't start unless the log files already exist. I create the path to the log file and put in an empty text document named the same as the expected log file and it starts right up.